# Проверка хэш кода архива

Tags: php

Как можно проверить хэш код архива?

Comment: Можно его посчитать.

Comment: узнать хэш-функцию имеющегося хэша, посчитать таковую для архива, сравнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для sha1 хэша:

```
$filename = 'file.zip';
$hash = 'SHA-1 хэш';
if (sha1_file($filename) == $hash) echo 'OK';
```

Для md5:

```
$filename = 'file.zip';
$hash = 'MD5 хэш';
if (md5_file($filename) == $hash) echo 'OK';
```